# Unexpected expression in C

Tags: c, pointers

May I know why I am getting an Error:

```
Unexpected Expression before 'INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR'?
```

I want to create a data type `INTL_MONEY_VALUE` which can store a floating-point number to represent a money value and currency. Also, `INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR`, being a pointer to the international money value type above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define COUNTRY 4
#define AMOUNT 20.20


int main()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        float value;
        char currency[COUNTRY];
    } INTL_MONEY_VALUE;

    INTL_MONEY_VALUE sg = { AMOUNT, "SGD" };

    // Pointer
    typedef INTL_MONEY_VALUE *INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR;

    printf("Amount: %s %.2f\n", sg.currency, sg.value);
    printf("Pointer: %s\n", *INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `typedef INTL_MONEY_VALUE *INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR;` -> `INTL_MONEY_VALUE *INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR` is a `typedef`, not an actual declared pointer variable. It doesn't even exist at runtime (it's just a convenience feature for declaring pointers to `INTL_MONEY_VALUE`). You can't dereference it, because "it" doesn't exist.

If you want to *declare* a pointer to `INTL_MONEY_VALUE`, you wouldn't use `typedef`, just:

```
INTL_MONEY_VALUE *INTL_MONEY_VALUE_PTR;  // possibly initialized to &sg
```

If you wanted to print the address of the actual declared instance of the struct (which is what the code seems to indicate it *should* do), you don't need the `typedef` or a declaration at all, you'd just do:

```
printf("Pointer: %p\n", &sg);
```